# How to reduce the number of function arguments and database table that has many fields in PHP

Tags: php, mysql

I want to pass some parameters in a method which i would use to insert data into my database. I have over 50 fields in the table i want to insert into.  The challenge is that, some of this parameters are optional and so, explicitly writing the parameters and table fields would be very hectic.

I thought of `public function addAd(...param){}` however, i won't have control over the optional params.

For the table fields, i thought of using `SELECT` to get the fields then pass it as array into `addTable` as `fields`. `"INSERT INTO adTable ($fields) VALUES (?,...)"`

Is there any way i can solve this problem?

**UPDATE**

```
private $col_names;
private $msg;
private function getAdsFields(){
        $sql = "SHOW COLUMNS FROM mall";
        $stmt = $this->db->run($sql);
        while ($row = $stmt->fetch()) {
            if ($row['Field'] != 'defaultColID') {
                array_push($this->col_names, $row['Field']);
            } 
        }
    }
```

```
public function createAd(...$params){
        $this->getAdsFields();
        //gets all the fields returned from getAdsFields then convert them to string
        $fields = implode(',', $this->col_names);

        if (empty($params)) {
            $this->message("empty", "All field must be filled");
        } else{
            // gets the total number of parameters passed
            $num = (count($params));
            // loops through the numbers and pushes '?' in to the each loop;
            $bind_array = [];
            for ($i=0; $i < $num; $i++) { 
                array_push($bind_array, '?');
            } 
            // coverts all the'?' in the array into strings;
            $bind = implode(',',$bind_array);

            $sql = "INSERT INTO mall ($fields) VALUES ($bind)";
            $stmt = $this->db->run($sql, $params);
            if ($stmt->rowCount() > 0) {
                $this->message("success", "Category added successfully");
            } else {
                $this->message("failed", "Something Went Wrong");
            }
        }
        return $this->msg;
    }
```

This actually worked, however, the only set back is that i cannot specify optional parameters.

Comment: Use an associative array with key-value pairs…?

Comment: Why not use an array for this? Also, why not check your database design for issues? A table with more than 50 fields, where some of them are optional, sounds like you are looking for a more normalized database design?

Comment: @NicoHaase, or probably a NoSQL solution would be better.

Comment: Have an array of allowed fields, and make sure your input names (or wherever your data is coming from) are the same as your table column names. Then you can check if your incoming data variable names are in the allowed list and build your statement dynamically. I agree though, that more than 50 fields sounds unmanageable.